# How to connect multiple docker container using link?

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I am trying to `link` mysql and php/nginx docker containers.
Here is the command I am running to connect the containers:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3005:80 --name nginxTest --link mysqlTest ubuntu
```

The php container contains this php file:

```
<?php
    $servername = "mysqlTest";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

But I am getting this error on accessing `127.0.0.1:3005`:

```
Connection failed: MySQL server has gone away
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

Comment: Check if you can connect to mysql docker image using regular way. Run docker inspect mysqlTest and get the ip assigned to it. It should look something like 172.**. Use that ip as $servername. If that succeeds then you can be sure that it is the link that is not working.

By the way a good way to do this would be to use docker-compose (or stack).
For eg. see this

Comment: Why won't you use docker-compose? You can either create a legit way of linking containers - make them join a custom network. Or use legacy [linking](https://rominirani.com/docker-tutorial-series-part-8-linking-containers-69a4e5bf50fb).